# Combining jquery functions - on() hover/mouseenter/mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of elements (lets call them '.my-elements') - some load on document ready, while others are loaded later via a pagination script.

I would like to set a variable according to whether or not the mouse is over these elements.  The code below works, but I suspect there is a better way...  Can I do this so I only have to reference the DOM once?

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.my-elements', function(){
    mouse_is_inside = true;
});

$(document).on('mouseleave','.my-elements', function(){
    mouse_is_inside = false;
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can bind to both together and check the [`event.type`](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.my-elements', function (ev) {
    mouse_is_inside = ev.type === 'mouseenter';
});
```

Or, if you want to keep them separate, [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has another syntax that takes an event map:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        mouse_is_inside = true;
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        mouse_is_inside = false;
    }
}, '.my-elements');
```

Comment: perfect solution :)

Answer (score 8):

Check out [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which is the same as:

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

UPDATE: I just realized you need to persist the events via the on() method. In that case, you can use an event map like so:

```
.on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        console.log('enter');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        console.log('bye!');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Almost all jQuery methods return objects, so you can chain them together:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.my-elements', function(){
    mouse_is_inside = true;
}).on('mouseleave','.my-elements', function(){
    mouse_is_inside = false;
});
```

Comment: word of warning, this will not work with live since it is not chainable.

Comment: NOTE: as of jQuery 1.9 `.live()` was removed

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
$(".my-elements").hover(function(eIn) {
    // do work for mouse over
}, 
function(eOut) {
    // do work for mouse out
});
```

> update and correction

realized you need more dynamic lock in which case Jonathan Lonowski's or Derek Hunziker's  is perfect

Comment: That will not work on the dynamically created elements.  **Quote OP:** _"...some load on document ready, while others are loaded later..."_

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can select for your elements instead of document.

```
$('.my-elements').on('mouseenter', function(){
    mouse_is_inside = true;
});
```

You could try a shortcut notation like this...

```
$('.my-elements').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    mouse_is_inside = !mouse_is_inside;
});
```

This will negate the value every time the mouse goes in or out, which should keep the mouse_is_inside variable set to the right value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-elements').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event){
    mouse_is_inside = event.type === 'mouseenter';
});
```

but its generally not a good idea to have a global variable incidating a event state

Comment: What are the issues with setting global variables as event state indicators?