# CSS Change on hover other element not working

Tags: html, wordpress, css, hover

I am trying to display sub-menu items and a div at the same time in Wordpress Genesis. But when I hover on the div the sub-menu disappear.

I am using the following code but it doesn't work

```
.sbclass:hover + #nav li:nth-child(3):hover ul, 
#nav li:nth-child(3) ul, 
#nav li:nth-child(3).sfHover ul, 
#nav li:nth-child(3) .submenu {
    visibility:visible !important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

You can check the third nav menu item menu here

```
http://174.120.233.154/~a348/nextmktg/jle/
```

Comment: Please provide an example on JSfiddle

Comment: Why don't you put your div inside the submenu?

Comment: It works fine in Chrome. What is your problem?

Comment: Your code implies that `.sbclass` is a *sibling* of `#nav`. So how can a user possibly hover over both elements at once?

Comment: What browser are you in? the :nth-child option only works in modern browsers.

Comment: the buttons itself are not build properly, i have to hover just above the text. show us a fiddle please :)

Comment: @Blazemonger is there any other way to achieve the desired output?

Comment: @JasonLydon I am using firefox 20.0.1

Comment: Yeah, I think @Blazemonger is right. You have two hover events fighting each other. Just make the hover happen on the `li:hover`. Or on `mouseenter`, add a class and remove the class on `mouseleave`. But either way, make the parent be responsibly for the hover event.

Comment: @JasonLydon Thank you mate can you please tell me how mouse enter and mouse leave will work with the class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

** ***The original post ended with the poster asking how to approach his problem with mouseenter/mouseleave, that is why this a javascript response to his css question*** **

Welp, your using jquery, so the most basic approach is below. There are prettier ways to do it as well.

```
$('selector').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).addClass('open');
});
$('selector').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

More here: [Combining jquery functions - on() hover/mouseenter/mouseleave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812062/combining-jquery-functions-on-hover-mouseenter-mouseleave)
And here: `http://api.jquery.com/on/`

Comment: Why are you suggesting a Javascript solution to a pure CSS problem? Whilst sometimes valid, you'd need very good reason to, which I don't see in this case.

Comment: @Niels do you have any solution using pure CSS?

Comment: @user2291220 Yes, Billy Matthews already suggested the right answer - you need a common parent to make this work. I'm willing to look at a practical implementation if I have a base JSfiddle to work from.

Comment: @JasonLydon my confusion arises from the fact that I, nor many people after me, will read all those comments before scrolling to the answer. The given answer does not support the original question, so one of the two or both need some rewriting to explain how you came from A to B. I'll remove the downvote though since it is on topic after all, my apologies (can't remove it now because of time since last edit).