# jQuery single handler for multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(150);
});

$('div').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).slideDown(150);
});
```

How can I combine this into something smaller?
Don't know enough jQuery / JS for this yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining jquery functions - on() hover/mouseenter/mouseleave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812062/combining-jquery-functions-on-hover-mouseenter-mouseleave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() { 
   ...
})
```

Another benefit of using `.on()` is event delegation, meaning any future `div`s will also trigger the events, instead of manually binding the event on them.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks! Accepting as answer when the system allows me to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .on() to bind a function to multiple events:

```
$('div').on('event1 event2', function(e) {
 $(this).slideToggle(150);
});
```